# Why i cant connect to external link .js ? (Using Xcode plugin phonegap)

Tags: javascript, html, xcode

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Doctor List</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />


</head>

<body>

    <div id="employeeListPage" data-role="page"  >

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Doctor</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <ul id="employeeList" data-role="listview" data-filter="true"></ul>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://panchoslimi.bugs3.com/MMC/js/DoctorList.js"></script>   


</body>
```

Why scr="http://panchoslimi.bugs3.com/mmc/js/DoctorList.js" not working ?  btw i need DoctorList.js on server side for my php file work. so i dont need doctorlist.js local on my xcode .. any solution ?

Comment: That link is broken, isn't it?

Comment: The link is *mostly* broken.  I got the JavaScript to load once, but most attempts fail with Service Temporarily Unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

When I attempt to load the link repeatedly in a browser (drop it into the URL bar), the source code loaded once.  On the other attempts, I get an error message:

> Service Temporarily Unavailable

Speak with the person providing the JavaScript code about the server not being reliably available.  You might see this behavior, for example, if they use load balancing and only some of their web servers are functioning correctly.

> btw i need DoctorList.js on server side for my php file work. so i dont need doctorlist.js local

The code you show is HTML.  HTML will execute in the client, not on the server.  Your markup to include the script appears to be correct.

JavaScript does not run in PHP.  To run it server-side, you need a server-side JavaScript engine.

Comment: look inside the script doctorlist.js i put $.getjson('./example.php') i know that javascript does not run in php so i use getjson open the link and see the script. i fix the link see it plz

Answer (score 0):

Try to load your js from local. Just download it and include in your project like scr="/js/DoctorList.js".

Comment: yes if load in local. but i need it on online server cz inside doctorlist script i use $.getson('example.php')